# Search iTunes by artist and song title

Tags: itunes

I found that I can search for a song term like so:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?media=music&entity=musicTrack&attribute=songTerm&term=xxxx
```

But what I really want to do is search by song title and the artist.  I can't seem to find syntax that would allow for that.  Is it possible?  I'm doing this from inside an iOS audio streaming application so I want to keep the returned results as small as possible so as to not use up much of a person's data plan.

Comment: To supplement Mark's answer, the **limit** parameter key may yield a finer search. So set limit to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Basically itunes search api sucks, a lot.
I was trying to do the same, but there isn't a direct way to search by song and artist, it searches both, and if your user misspelled the name of the song or the artist, the search can give you bad results.

So my solution was basically use a prefilter first to correct that, using [echonest](http://developer.echonest.com/), to search by artist name and song name, then show a dropdown (you can choose other method like "Do you mean: ...?" with links to correct url for search) and then use what Fahad says, putting first the name of the artist and then the name of the song. Don't forget to encode those.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this, the simplest would be something like

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=slipknot+duality

For further information regarding the [iTunes Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searchexamples)

Answer (score 0):

you can concatinate artist name and song title using + sign inplace of space between those words as given below:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=the+beatles+let+it+be

in the above url "**the beatles**" is the artist name and "**let it be**" is the track name. 
That's it your done.

Comment: And if you do that you'll get nothing but a bunch of covers and karaoke because it will only return results where "the beatles" is in the title. You have to only include the title in the term and filter the results yourself. The iTunes API still sucks today.